# How to design a Munit4 test to execute a partial of a flow?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, munit

I have a subflowA which calls another subflowB.
eg: subflowA : doing authentication, with hTTP request
 subflow B: after successful authentication, it retrieves data.

I would like to test subflowA's authentication process only.
If I create munit and select a flow for execution (ie: subflowA), which has the reference to subflowB too.
So. my test continues to run other flows too.
How Can i break munit4 to run only authentication process?

eg :

```
<subflow name='A'>
  <http :request .....>
   </http:request>
   ..
  <flow-ref 
            name="subflowB" />
</subflow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest Way to achieve is by : create a subFlow C which contains the following

```
<subflow name=' C'>
  <flow-ref name="subflowA" />
  <flow-rer name = "subflowB"/>
</subflow>
```

In this case, you can test subflowA and subflowB separately without any issues.

or you can stick to your current design and mock the subflowB as https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/1.3/mock-message-processor#defining-mocks

Answer (score 1):

Mocking is the best way for you to avoid getting into `subflowB`

[The link sent it above should be right](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/1.3/mock-message-processor#defining-mocks)